# What happens if I send a Custom dimension whitout configure in GA?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a "Google Analytics Settings" variable in GTM with some custom dimensions configured, but that dimensions are not configured in GA.
So now I'm curious, how this data is sent and what happens in this case? Is it a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply as if you are not sending it to Google Analytics, meaning you will not see it in reports.